# Asp.net Core Razor persist data in a view over reload

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

In my Razor app I can add in the details below and return the Result in a list, as well as area and cost.
How do I persist that list of Results so it saves multiple results?

[image]

I am posting the results as

```
<form method="post">
```

and using the carpet class as

```
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public Carpet? carpet { get; set; }
```

My OnPostAsync is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
some code....
carpet.FinalCost = carpetOperations.TotalInstallCost(carpet);
carpet.Results.Add("Room area " + carpet.RoomArea + "sqm $" + carpet.FinalCost);
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

But I want to persist the data in my carpet.Results List across different entries.

I have also tried it as a Property

```
  public List<string> CarpetResults { get; set; }
```

and instantiated it in the constructor

```
 public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        CarpetResults = new List<string>();
    }
```

But it still resets after every page load.

Comment: Why don't you use Database to save the data, Then every page load, Read the data from db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Database to achieve this, Every time the page loads. it reads the data from the database, So it will not resets after every page load.

Because you don't provide enough code, So i can just write a simple demo to show.

```
//I use this simple class to create the database
public class Carpet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public int Area { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        //this property will save the "Room area xx sqm $ xx" 
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in `PageModel`

```
        //this property will show results in page
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Carpet> carpets { get; set; }
  
        //this property will pass data from page to controller
        [BindProperty]
        public Carpet carpet { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            carpets = _context.carpets.ToList();
            return Page();
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Carpet carpet)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //........your code
            
            
            carpet.Text = "Room area " + carpet.Area + "sqm $" + carpet.Cost;
            _context.carpets.Add(carpet);
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

In page, You can use `@foreach(xx)` to get the items in `List<Carpet>`, Then display them on the page

```
@*your page code*@


<h1>results</h1>
@foreach (var item in @Model.carpets)
{
    <div>
        <h5>@item.Area</h5>
         <h5>@item.Cost</h5>
         <h5>@item.Text</h5>
    </div>
}
```

I just wrote a simple demo, you may need to add your css and js. You can also use session to achieve it,
But I think it's easier to use a database.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the same I found a solution without using a db. I am making a small app that is not public facing and only as a teaching tool, so security is not so much an issue, and I didn't want a db.

So I created a static class, and just used that.

```
  public static class StaticList
{
    public static List<string>? StaticStudentResults { get; set; } = new 
 List<string>();
}
```

And in my codebehind I just passed the data to the same list structure held on the page

```
StudentResults.AddRange(StaticList.StaticStudentResults);
```

Naturally this could be a huge security hole and do not recommend it for public facing sites.